# Encoding with readtext

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, nlp

I want to do some text analysis based on data stored as a .csv file, but I run into problems regarding the encoding with the `readtext` package.

To illustrate my problem, I created the following file in Excel, saving it as .csv (UTF-8):

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      c_text         |       c_id       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      München        |        aa        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Laïrie        |        bb        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Mános        |        cc        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Then, I load the data in R as follows:

```
text_raw <- readtext::readtext("path/test_encoding.csv"),
                   encoding = "UTF-8",
                   text_field = "c_text")
text_raw
```

The output is:

```
readtext object consisting of 3 documents and 1 docvar.
# Description: data.frame [3 x 3]
  doc_id              text              c_id 
  <chr>               <chr>             <chr>
1 test_encoding.csv.1 "\"MÃ¼nchen\"..." aa   
2 test_encoding.csv.2 "\"LaÃ¯rie\"..."  bb   
3 test_encoding.csv.3 "\"MÃ¡nos\"..."   cc
```

If I then write the object to a .csv file, the output is once again different. The command `write.csv(text_raw, file = "path", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")` yields the following:

```
MÃƒÂ¼nchen
LaÃƒÂ¯rie
MÃƒÂ¡nos
```

Some additional information:

- I am using a Windows machine, and my `sys.getLocale()` is `English_United Kingdom.1252` (apparently, this cannot be changed to UTF-8)
- Even if I specify other encodings in the `readtext()` function, (e.g., "utf8", "Windows-1252", "ISO8859-1"), the output doesn't change. However, given that I explicitly save the test file as utf-8, I don't understand what's going on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It might just be a problem with printing it on the screen (that happened to me with RStudio on `English_United Kingdom.1252`). You could write the table back to a csv and open it with Excel or a text editor to see if the coding is really messed up.

Comment: What package does the `readtext` function come from? That does't appear to be a base R function.

Comment: Apologies, I updated the question to show the results of writing a csv file, and specified that the `readtext` function comes from the `readtext` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a pull request since this was an issue in the `readtext` package:

https://github.com/quanteda/readtext/pull/151

Until this PR is either accepted or the problem otherwise fixed, you can use my fork to solve this problem:

```
remotes::install_github("JBGruber/readtext")
```

## Update

The PR was approved so install the new package version via:

```
remotes::install_github("quanteda/readtext")
```

And then it should work:

```r
df <- structure(list(c_text = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Laïrie", 
                                                                  "Mános", "München"), class = "factor"), c_id = structure(1:3, .Label = c("aa", 
                                                                                                                                           "bb", "cc"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                -3L))
write.csv(df,
          "~/test.csv",
          row.names = FALSE,
          fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
text_raw <- readtext::readtext("~/test.csv",
                               encoding = "UTF-8",
                               text_field = "c_text")

text_raw
#> readtext object consisting of 3 documents and 1 docvar.
#> # Description: data.frame [3 x 3]
#>   doc_id     text             c_id 
#>   <chr>      <chr>            <chr>
#> 1 test.csv.1 "\"München\"..." aa   
#> 2 test.csv.2 "\"Laïrie\"..."  bb   
#> 3 test.csv.3 "\"Mános\"..."   cc
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>